# jupyter lab - suppress console output

Tags: linux, jupyter

I am running jupyter lab 4.4.0 on redhat 6. I am trying to start the lab in the background so that the app's output is not appearing in my console anymore.

`$ jupyer lab & > /dev/null 2>&1`

But the console still shows output from the jupyter app (e.g. the startup messages and any saving logs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rewrite your command like this:

```
$ jupyter lab >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

And also is wise to add nohup to avoid stop of app if you logout

```
$ nohup jupyter lab >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Your suggestion is good but jupyter is not spelled correctly. Copying and pasting your command would not work. Thanks

Comment: @HermanJaramillo corrected :)